# Trouble compiling libtiff 4.0 beta on linux

Tags: linux, gcc, compilation, libtiff

I'm trying to compile libtiff 4.0 beta to a static library on Ubuntu 10.10 using gcc. It seems to compile the libjpeg and libz fine, which are dependencies. Here is the error I am getting

```
    libtool: link: ( cd ".libs" && rm -f "libtiff.la" && ln -s "../libtiff.la" "libtiff.la" )
\
    source='tif_stream.cxx' object='tif_stream.lo' libtool=yes \
    DEPDIR=.deps depmode=none /bin/bash ../config/depcomp \
    /bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.      -c -o tif_stream.lo tif_stream.cxx
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -c tif_stream.cxx  -o .libs/tif_stream.o
../libtool: line 990: g++: command not found
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your compile chain is incomplete. On ubuntu, try installing the package called build-essentials. That should pull in all the tools needed to compile c and c++ libraries.

Comment: installed this, still unable to compile, getting exit values of 1 with no error printed and still no libtiff.a file or other static library file.

Comment: It was the make file, it was really messed up, had to start from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

​Install​ the `g++` package​.​

Comment: Now I am getting this error instead.
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++   -no-undefined -version-info 5:3:0   -o libtiffxx.la -rpath /usr/local/lib tif_stream.lo ../libtiff/libtiff.la ../port/libport.la -ljpeg -lz -lm -lc 
libtool: link: unsupported hardcode properties
libtool: link: See the libtool documentation for more information.
libtool: link: Fatal configuration error.
make[2]: *** [libtiffxx.la] Error 1